# Numpy fancy/advanced indexing independent of dimensions

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

The following code gives me the desired result, but I am wondering if there is a more universal approach for applying it to 1D and 2D arrays, e.g. using fancy/advanced indexing?

```
import numpy as np

df1 = np.array([-5, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3])
df2 = np.array([[-5, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], [-5, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3]])

def func(df):
    if df.ndim == 1:
        cum_cf = df.cumsum()
        ny = np.argmax(cum_cf > 0)-1
        n = cum_cf[ny]
        p = df[ny+1]
    else:
        cum_cf = df.cumsum(axis=1)
        ny = np.argmax(cum_cf > 0, axis=1)-1
        rows = np.arange(df.shape[0])
        n = cum_cf[rows, ny]
        p = cum_cf[rows, ny+1]
    value = 1 + ny - (n/p)
    return value

print(func(df1))
>>> 3.0
print(func(df2))
>>> [3. 4.]
```

So this is more about cleaning my code, as I guess that I could omit the rows statement and put the variables n and p outside the if else condition. Can I do this using Ellipsis? Basically, it is subsetting all rows, but there is no row for a 1D array.

Comment: `func(np.atleast_2d(input_ar))` with `func` using just the ELSE part of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the comments, this is the right way to go?

```
def func(df):
    df = np.atleast_2d(df)
    cum_cf = df.cumsum(axis=1)
    ny = np.argmax(cum_cf > 0, axis=1)-1
    rows = np.arange(df.shape[0])
    n = cum_cf[rows, ny]
    p = cum_cf[rows, ny+1]
    value = 1 + ny - (n/p)
    return value
```

Comment: Sure, but look at the code for `np.atleast_2d`.  It has an `if/elif/else` that checks for 0, 1 and more `ndim`.  So you are just burying the `ndim` testing in another function - which is perfectly good Python programming style.